# Automation Testing with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I export my test case from Selenium IDE to WebDriver, and trying to run it, FireFox browser always opens up and test case running there. But how can I run my test case in GoogleChrome or Opera in Selenuim WebDriver?

Comment: Did you google this? What have you tried? Post your code that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In  your code must be something like that:

```
IWebDriver driver = new FireFoxDriver();
```

Simply change it to:

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

The code above is written on C#.

On Java it's really similar. Click Ctr+F and type "Firefox". Search in whole solution. This way you are gonna find where your driver is set.